# keep focus on parent div jquery

Tags: jquery

My problem is about a restaurant site.

I want to develop a catalog showing all the food items.
On each food item details are shown when user mousehover that food item.

A div appears over that image with details along with which the user has to select a restaurant name from the dropdown list to get the price of the food item for in that restuarnt. But when mouse goes over the the dropdown box the div showing details mouse down .ie the hover attribute does not remain .

Both, the details and dropdown are on the same div.

Comment: Welcome new user! post the code that you have tried so far([How to ask good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Answer (score 0):

Just Guessing, because don't have any HTML or JavaScript code to make a better answer, so I'm gonna make assumptions.

If you show the div.details when hovering an image, but you dont want to hide that div when hover out the image, you want it when hovering out the parent of the img.

```
$("#divParent img").mouseover(function(){
    $("#divDetails").show();
});

$("#divParent").mouseout(function(){
    $("#divDetails").hide();
});
```

Please, let me know if this don't fit your case and in that case, provide more info so we can provide you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following for both the attributes as both of the are child to the same DIV according to what I understood from your description.

```
$(this).parent().focus();
```